# HTTPUrlConenction check to see if server supports resume

Tags: java, android

When downloading a file with HTTPUrlConnection is there a way to check if the server supports resume before attempting to resume a file download?

Either I am doing something wrongor the server doesnt support resume, how can i check first?

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dir/", filename );
                if (file.exists()) {
          crashes here--->          //c.setRequestProperty("Range", "Bytes="+(file.length())+"-");

                  Log.d("file already exists", filename);
                }
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.setDoInput(true);
                c.connect();

                f = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH_op), true);//set true so if file exists it will append
```

LOGCAT

```
03-17 14:55:23.746: WARN/System.err(11196):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
```

I found out if the server supports resume and it does, I found this out by checking the Accept-Range reponse as Nuvaak suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that line would crash your program, if the server does not support the `Range` header, it will simply ignore it.

For the question, you may need to issue an extra connection and check the response header `Accept-Ranges`, if its value is `bytes`, you are lucky that it supports the `Range` request header, if it's `none`, then don't try it.

Comment: I tried what you said and the value is indeed bytes, however whenever I uncomment the line I get a filenot found exception

Comment: That exception has nothing to do with the `Range` header, checkout javadoc for FileOutputStream for more info on the exception. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean)

Comment: which means there is something is wrong with file.size(), not with your connection.